# Json Model Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, webserver, jsonmodel

Getting the following error while using JSONMODEL to hit a web service.

> "Error Domain=JSONModelErrorDomain Code=2 "Bad network response.
>   Probably the JSON URL is unreachable." UserInfo=0xa1aeea0
>   {NSLocalizedDescription=Bad network response. Probably the JSON URL is
>   unreachable.}"

Here is my Code

```
NSDate *currentDate=[NSDate date];
NSDictionary *dict=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"100",@"userId",@"ios",@"platform",currentDate,@"currentDate",@"1",@"numberOfPage",@"10",@"numberOfRowToFetch",@"1",@"category",nil];
NSString  *urlStr=[@"http://www.lptpl.tk/teleshka/admin/index.php?r=jsoner/homeProductList" stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
[JSONHTTPClient postJSONFromURLWithString:urlStr params:dict completion:^(id json, JSONModelError *err){
    LoginDataModelClass *responce = [[LoginDataModelClass alloc] initWithDictionary: json error:nil]; 
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:Login_Responce object:responce];
}];
```

2.Following error occured while passing body string.

**"The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “lptpl.tk” which could put your confidential information at risk."**

Comment: Can you show your code to reach the web service?

Comment: Your Error is already stating that the URL is unreachable, have you tried accessing it in browser?

Comment: Please add more detail. What service are you trying access, what exactly are you posting to the service, and do they give any more details as far as what their error codes mean?

Comment: its working fine if web service is built in cake PHP framework,but getting the above error   if web service is built in YII framework. please reply asps.Thanks

Comment: I assume you are making an HTTP request to this web service. Try using a tool like Fiddler to see exactly what you are sending and what the server is returning.

Comment: Why are you using `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` on a string literal that contains no spaces anyway?

Comment: Also I get: `HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 0 [text/html]`.

Comment: i have tried by trimming the space also.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by my own.Problem was that i was passing a date type parameter, while json model only support either String Type or number Type parameters.